# /var has most of the drive space. Need / to have most of it

Tags: mount, partition

So when my host setup my dedi, they seemed to apply most of the drive space to /var

I am on cpanel, and need most of the space for the /home directory where all the accounts and data are.

But on previous dedi's ive had the majority of the drive was just assigned to /

This is what I get when I do a

```
    df -h


    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    rootfs                 20G   16G  3.7G  81% /
    /dev/root              20G   16G  3.7G  81% /
    none                   16G  404K   16G   1% /dev
    /dev/md2               92G   14G   74G  16% /var
    /dev/loop0            4.0G  139M  3.7G   4% /tmp
    /dev/loop0            4.0G  139M  3.7G   4% /var/tmp
    /dev/root              20G   16G  3.7G  81% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
    /dev/root              20G   16G  3.7G  81% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
```

Not sure why its like this. Can I somehow use the 92G for / rather then /var without losing any data and things going tits up?

I am on centos 6.

Comment: Can be done, but would require delicate juggling. Not for the faint of heart (and even less for the backup-less).

Answer (score 3):

`/var` is not temporary, so you can use it.  **You'll need to stop all access to `/home` for a few minutes while the data moves,** since these are probably different physical partitions. Ie, stop the server!  It won't take long. Also: *do this as root*, not via sudo. Next:

```
cd /
mv home home_mnt
```

I'm using a different and unique name in case there's a real `/var/home` or something.  Keeps things tidy and hopefully more clear.  Now:

```
mv home_mnt var
```

What was `/home` is now `/var/home_mnt`.  But you are going to use it via a symlink:

```
ln -s /var/home_mnt /home
```

Presto.  Try `cd /home` to check.  "Home" is a good directory to move because it is non-essential to the base system.  Don't try this with, eg, `/usr` -- it'll hurt, a lot.

Do not move anything into `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` either.  Those will disappear.

Comment: Ok cool brilliant, I will give that a try.

I am thinking that a lot of space will be taken up with /usr too from all the mysql data.

Is there no way to just reassign the 92GB to / rather than /var ?

I don't want to have to reinstall the OS and everything if I don't have to.

Thanks